# Button Xamarin/C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, button

I created a buttons in Xamarin I am setting up their border color in code as i want them to change the border color once they are clicked to show the active button.

```
protected void EnglishToCzech_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{      
    Button englishToCzech = (Button)sender;      
    englishToCzech.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");                 
}    

protected void CzechToEnglish_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{       
    Button czechToEnglish = (Button)sender;       
    czechToEnglish.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");                
}   

private  void English_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    Button english = (Button)sender;       
    english.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");    
}
```

This works but once they are clicked the border stays red. Now I am not sure if I should just create a method with switch or if there is any better approach?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want the border to turn red and then revert back to previous color?

Comment: Remember to accept an answer or edit your question if an answer has not been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

Change `Thread.Sleep(20000)` to how many milliseconds you want it to change for and change  `english.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("");` to include the original color

```
private  void English_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    Button english = (Button)sender;       
    english.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#da2c43");  
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20000);

        english.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("");  
    });  
}
```